# DAML Sand box error: Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion' has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required

Tags: daml

Getting below error when I start sandbox. I think we need use jdk8 as per the DAML doc.

daml sandbox --scenario Main:setup .daml/dist/quickstart-0.0.1.dar

Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
daml-helper: Received ExitFailure 2 when running
Raw command: java -jar "C:\Users\santh\AppData\Roaming\daml\sdk\0.13.21\sandbox/sandbox.jar" --scenario Main:setup .daml/dist/quickstart-0.0.1.dar

Answer (score 1):

During my initial setup, I have faced the similar issue.  It may be because of an existing Java installation in your machine.

You can try the below options to fix this issue.

**Option 1**:
1. Check if you have more than one version of JAVA in machine.
2. If yes, uninstall everything and do the clean installation.  Make sure your Environment Path variable(s) are got set properly.

or

**Option 2**:
1) Download the latest JDK in Zip format "jdk-12.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip"
2) Extract it manually in your local drive.
3) Manually update your Environment Path variables (ref. https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10).

I hope it will help you to fix your problem.

Cheers,
Augustine